# Get charge ID after Stripe payment and issue refund in PHP

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe to process my payments in PHP with the API found here https://github.com/myg0v/Simple-Bootstrap-Stripe-Payment-Form

I'm using the following code to issue payment:

```
$charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array("amount" => $amount,
                                "currency" => "$currency",
                                "card" => $stripetoken,
                "description" => $email));
```

Will the following code retrive the charge_id and refund the user?

```
 $charge_id = $charge->stripe_charge_id;

 $refund = Stripe_Refund::create(array(
  "charge" => "$charge_id"
));
```

Comment: Isn't that more of a business logic question you should ask Stripe directly? Doesn't really strike me as a programming issue.

Comment: It's a question about PHP interacting with their API. I'm asking if it is the correct way to do so, if it will work or if there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This syntax is for old versions of [Stripe's PHP library](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php#stripe-php-bindings) (1.x). You should make sure that you use the latest version (currently 4.4.0).

Stripe's [API reference](https://stripe.com/docs/api/php) includes samples for every request and language. You can check the sample requests for:

- [creating a charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge)
- [creating a refund](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_refund)

Basically:

```
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    "amount" => $amount,
    "currency" => $currency,
    "source" = $token,
    "description" => "Charge for $email"
));

$refund = \Stripe\Refund::create(array(
    "charge" => $charge->id
));
```